# Facebook Application request limit reached (#4)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a "social wall" on a website, so I use the Facebook API to get some posts for a specified Facebook page. I'm not using any Facebook SDK, i'm just making cURL calls with the URLs.

To retrieve the posts, I use Javascript. With an Ajax command I call a PHP file which make the cURL calls to Facebook.

When I work in local in my computer, everything works fine and I get all the elements.

But when I put my code online, I have this error

```
OAuthException (#4) Application request limit reached
```

I searched everywhere and I tried to put the elements in a localStorage variable. Again, in local I'm getting correctly all the elements. But when I test online, even at the very first API call, I get this error again in my console...

I'm just asking Facebook for 20 posts :

- I retrieve the page feed (https://graph.facebook.com/myPageID/posts?limit=20&access_token=myToken)
- With Javascript I parse this feed, and with every ID I make a call to get details like this : https://graph.facebook.com/myPostID?access_token=myToken
- Then I have the posts details and I make another call for every post to get the picture adding this : /myPostID?fields=full_picture&access_token=myToken

So if I'm right, 1 call for the feed, 20 calls for the posts, and 20 calls for the pictures. That's 41 calls only.

What should I do to make it work fine ?

EDIT:

Here is my CURL code :

getToken is launched one time if the token is wrong.

getFeed is launched one time to get the feed.

getPost and getPicture are launched 20 times each.

```
function fetchUrl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    // You may need to add the line below
    // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

    $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    return $feedData;
}

// Génère le token lié à l'appli fb
function facebook_getToken(){
    global $FB_token, $FB_app_id, $FB_app_secret;

    $FB_token = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $FB_app_id . "&client_secret=" . $FB_app_secret . "&grant_type=client_credentials");

    $FB_token = substr($FB_token, 13);
}

// Récupère les derniers posts de la page fb
function facebook_getFeed($pageID){
    global $FB_token;

    $json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $pageID . "/posts?limit=20&access_token=" . $FB_token);

    $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

    if(array_key_exists("error", $json_decoded)){
        if($json_decoded->{'error'}->{'message'} == "Invalid OAuth access token signature."){
            $_POST["a_t"] = null;
            return null;
        }
    }
    else{
        $json_object = substr($json_object, 0, -1);
        $json_object = $json_object . ", \"access_token\": \"" . $FB_token . "\"}";

        return $json_object;
    }
}

// Récupère les informations du post fb souhaité
function facebook_getPost($postID){
    global $FB_token;

    $thePost = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $postID . "?access_token=" . $FB_token);

    return $thePost;
}

// Récupère l'image du post fb en paramètre
function facebook_getPicture($postID){
    global $FB_token;

    $thePicture = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $postID . "?fields=full_picture&access_token=" . $FB_token);

    return $thePicture;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick guess: Are you sure that the code doesn't loop the request somehow? Could you add your CURL code here?

Comment: @Shamppi I don't think so, how could it be possible to have a code that is working fine offline but not online ?
I have edited my question (I added the CURL code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you're doing. You can retrieve all the post's details via

```
/{page_id}/posts?limit=20&fields=id,message,full_picture
```

where `{page_id}` is a numeric id of an existing page. You can skip the 20 requests for posts and the 20 requests for the full pictures.

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Reading

Comment: Wow, I was doing it wrong until the beginning. Thank you, it was as simple as that...